# Center Form with Destroying Auto complete (Bootstrap Tokenfield)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tokenfield

How do you center a form from bootstrap tokenfield without making the autocomplete suggestions also become centered?

An example would be:

http://jsfiddle.net/H7u63/34/

So far, I have tried

```
#test {
    text-align: center;
}

.form-horizontal { 
   margin: 0 auto;
   width:800px;
}
```

However, as you can see in the example, all the results also become centered and this behavior is not optimal. I have also tried setting
`margin-left` and `margin-right` to auto but that does not seem to cause the form to get centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
.tokenfield {
    text-align: left;
}
```